# laravel 5 pagination appends function issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I have code and url like below. I do not know how to use that function properly.

I believe appends function would call some other function to append conditioned query right ? but I dont know where it call or I can write those functions.

I never wrote any function for search but it somehow search text .. I do not know how.

```
URL : ?search=test&status=Resolved

    $paginator->appends(request()->query->all());

    array:2 [
      "search" => "test"
      "status" => "Resolved"
    ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a search form or paginate with previous search result? I mean going to second page or third page with current search result?

Answer (score 1):

`append` lets you add extra parameters to the pagination URL, e.g. sorting variable etc. By default, the pagination links would only contain the `page` parameter.

For example, to append `&sort=votes` to each pagination link, you should make the following call to appends:

```
{!! $paginator->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() !!}
```

So in your code, you just need to add `->links()` to the end and add the code to a blade to display the pagination links:

```
{!! $paginator->appends(request()->query->all())->links(); !!}
```